# Round counting for rock paper scissors game (potential jquery issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to the coding world and am creating a rock paper scissors game for a class.  The game is set up so the user can select rock, paper, or scissors using three different buttons and the computer generates a random choice.  After ten rounds, the game cuts off and the user has the option to play again.  If the user opts to play the third set of ten rounds, the round counter starts incrementing by 2 rounds per turn instead of one.  I am unsure how to solve this issue- any help would be appreciated!

This is the code in question (so far)

```js
function roundIncrement() {
  RPS.gameState.roundCount++;
  $("#roundNumber").html(RPS.gameState.roundCount);
  console.log(RPS.gameState.roundCount);
};
```

[Here is my fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/8dcddzp9/embedded/result/)  I took a bunch of .js files and put them into the javascript portion.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Move the reset-button event outside of the round count check.

```
$(document).on("click", "#reset-button", function() {
      restoreDefault();
  });
```

Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8dcddzp9/1/

Edit:

Also, have you noticed that your round number does not equal the ties + wins + losses?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seemed to work.  Would you mind going through the logic why doing that made it work?  And yes, I was just thinking about that round number thing.

Comment: @wariofan1 You do not generally have event listeners inside of nested logic/functions. Since your event only binds on the reset button being clicked, you would have your code manipulate when the reset button is visible to click (which you've already done). The code was problematic because the event listener was only available when the roundCount was 10, for the brief moment of that condition being checked.